# Haskell - Expose hidden package permanently

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-diagrams

I am a beginner when it comes to Haskell and I have been following the [quickstart tutorial for diagrams](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/quickstart.html).

I installed Haskell with ghcup and diagrams with `cabal install diagrams --lib` (the tutorial mentions `cabal sandbox init`, but apparently this is outdated).

When I try to compile the first example (with `ghc --make example.hs`), I get the following error:

```
/home/me/example.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Diagrams.Prelude’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘diagrams-lib-1.4.3’.
    You can run ‘:set -package diagrams-lib’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import Diagrams.Prelude
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/home/me/example.hs:5:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘diagrams-svg-1.4.3’.
    You can run ‘:set -package diagrams-svg’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
5 | import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I could prevent this error by doing `ghc example.hs  -package diagrams-lib -package diagrams-svg`, but I could not find a way to do this permanently.

Comment: Shouldn't you compile with `cabal exec -- ghc --make example.hs`, so with the `cabal exec -- `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled using the [cabal file](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-1.10.1.0/doc/users-guide/#packages). Your `example.cabal` file will contain a section like this

```
library example
   exposed-modules: 
      Example   -- Assumes your example.hs contains "module Example where ..."
   build-depends:
      diagrams-lib,
      diagrams-svg
```

Then you compile using `cabal build` or `cabal install`.